# How can Xcode (iOS app) use a swift package hosted in private repos?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure, swift-package-manager

How can Xcode (iOS app) use a swift package hosted in private repos?

Context: **Without** using the Xcode `svm` provider accounts: gitlab, GitHub, bitbucket (the ones Xcode lists)

I have the source code for a private swift package hosted in Azure Repos, for the company I work with. **How can I add this package using Xcode?**

Comment: If you open the Xcode preferences window, select accounts, then click the little + on the left. Authenticate with the provider (like GitHub) and you should be all good.

Comment: thank you for the feedback Jake

Answer (score 0):

I try adding the repository URL (from Azure Repos) using the Xcode interface, but it did not let me add it that time. I believe it was because I was using the public HTTPS url.

When I tried adding using the SSH url, it was added. I build and ran the app and it works as expected.

It even list the dependency under the `Package.resolved` manifest. (Notice: local packages won't get listed in this manifest, the fact that the package is now listed and showing the repo URL means is now pulling the source code from the repository itself)

[image]

Comment: Apple does explicitly mentions the above in the documentation. I just really losted in translation  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/building_swift_packages_or_apps_that_use_them_in_continuous_integration_workflows 